# How to get particular node value from XML Store in Sencha Touch

Tags: xml-parsing, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have following XML Structure and I want to get Fields tag value dynamically on the basis of ***Tab, Topic, SubTopic and Screen***; is this possible? Plz let me know appropriate solution.

XML Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
<ABC TYPE="Tab">
<Trans TYPE="Topic">
  <Rpt TYPE="SubTopic">
    <File TYPE="Screen">
      <Fields>
        <Tin>10</Tin>
        <Pin>8</Pin>
      </Fields>
    </File>
  </Rpt>
</Trans>
</ABC>
<XYZ TYPE="Tab">
<Trans TYPE="Topic">
  <Rpt TYPE="SubTopic">
    <File TYPE="Screen">
      <Fields>
        <Tin>10</Tin>
        <Pin>8</Pin>
      </Fields>
    </File>
  </Rpt>
</Trans>
  </XYZ>
 </Settings>
```

**Model Structure:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ScreenValidation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'Tin',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pin',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

XMLStore Strucuter:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.ScreenValidation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.ScreenValidation'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.ScreenValidation',
        storeId: 'ScreenValidation',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'ScreenValidation.xml',
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                record: 'Fields'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to modify the xml structure I would recommend doing that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Setting>
    <type>Tab</type>
    <transType>Topic</transType>
    <rptType>SubTopic</rptType>
    <fileType>Screen</fileType>
    <Fields>
      <Tin>10</Tin>
      <Pin>8</Pin>
      </Fields>
    </File>
  </Setting>

  ....ETC
</Settings
```

If you don't have access to the api so that you can change the format I think you are going to be stuck either:

1: getting the xml response with a standard ajax request and either parsing your xml result by hand or using a library then manually populating the MyApp.model.ScreenValidation object.

or

2: extend/override the [Ext.data.reader.Xml](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml) class and making it parse out the information you want into your model.

I hope you have access to the api because both of the latter solutions sound horrible. Also, I have never attempted to solve a problem like this so I may be overlooking a more simple solution.

I look forward to hearing how you get this working.

Good luck, Brad